# Can I stop Filter Items from truncating on Column Filter Dropdown (...)

Tags: document-library, lookup-column, filter, filtermulivalue

I have a Lookup field on a Library which is related to a List of Items.

After these items reach a certain length, the items in the Filter Dropdown get truncated, and a '...' is added to the end of them.

For example:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

gets shortened to

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy...

Is there any way to stop this from happening? My client would like the entire item to display in the Filter Dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width and text-overflow:ellipsis from the CSS on the object
Or overrule it with your own CSS